# Get current's logged in user's employee ID to set default search filter

Tags: xml, odoo

```
    <record id="hr.open_view_employee_list_my" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Search Filter</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_employee_id": #}</field>
    </record>
```

I want to replace # with the current user's employee_id so that everytime I go to Employee app the default search will automatically search for current's user employee ID.

I have tried replacing # with context.get(employee_id) but it doesn't work. If anyone can help it'll be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a `default` to get the employee id

```
def _get_employee_id(self):
    employee_rec = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid)], limit=1)
    return employee_rec.id

employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee", default=_get_employee_id, readonly=True, required=True)
```

```
<record id="hr.open_view_employee_list_my" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Search Filter</field>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_employee_id": employee_id}</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `user.id` in XML to get the current user loggedin.